# Elastic search 2.3 wildcard query not returning results for exact match

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to use wildcard search using elastic search 2.3 using its official PHP client.

I am facing a issue which is like this:

Case 1. When i search for word **wood**, it returns the words which are having woodman, hollywood and hollywoodbolly.

Case 2. But when i search for **hollywood**, it does not return the words which are having hollywood in them.

However, everything is working fine when done in query string like this:

```
"query" => [
            "query_string" => [
                "query" => "*$keyword*",
                "analyze_wildcard" => true,
                "fields" => $fields
            ]
        ],
```

But when used like follwing, Case 2 is not working:

```
"query" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    [
                        "wildcard" => [
                            'name' => "*$keyword*",
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "nested" => [
                            "path" => "address",
                            "score_mode" => "max",
                            "query" => [
                                "bool" => [
                                    "must" => [..match[] parameters..]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help.

EDIT:

**NOTE: I have made the field as not_analysed.**

My query is returning **cardboard** when searching for **card** but not returning **cardboard** when searching for **cardboard**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch supports [wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) only on `not_analyzed` fields

So if you would like to use the wildcard capability you could either use it under the `query_string` object, or change the mapping for that field to `index: not_analyzed` and then you would be able to do a wildcard search.

Comment: I have made the field as not_analysed

     `'name' => [
                                "type" => "string",
                                "index" => "not_analyzed",
                                ]`

But still not able to do it.

Comment: My query is returning **cardboard** when searching for **card** but not returning  **cardboard** when searching for  **cardboard** .

Comment: Are you sure that the field is mapped to be `not_analyzed`? Check the `/_mapping` endpoint to make sure. I just tested it and I can search for `*cardboard*` when a field has `name: "cardboard'` using the wildcard query and get the right results back.